# Can't not install any package throw pecl?

Tags: php, macos, pecl

When I try to install xdebug on my mac, and not just this package any thing!

```
pecl install xdebug
```

I got this error:

```
downloading xdebug-3.0.3.tgz ...
Starting to download xdebug-3.0.3.tgz (215,952 bytes)
.............................................done: 215,952 bytes
87 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20200930
Zend Module Api No:      20200930
Zend Extension Api No:   420200930
autom4te: need GNU m4 1.4 or later: /usr/bin/m4
ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

I just follow [this](https://superuser.com/questions/470879/pecl-install-error-after-upgrading-to-osx-10-8) sluation it does not work for me!

```
➜  ~ which m4
/usr/bin/m4
➜  ~ which autom4te
/usr/local/bin/autom4te
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the important line of your error message:

> autom4te: need GNU m4 1.4 or later: /usr/bin/m4

There's a venerable old UNIX program called [m4](https://linux.die.net/man/1/m4) used by pecl to set up your extension. An incorrect version is installed on your system.

So do this if you're on Ubuntu / Debian.

```
sudo apt -y remove m4
sudo apt -y install m4
```

and try again.

On MacOS, [read this](https://superuser.com/questions/668746/install-gnu-m4-1-4-or-later-on-osx).

Comment: Thanks I just run ( xcode-select --install ) and it's working now!